# Bumping unconfirmed transaction with sendrawtransaction

Tags: bitcoin-core, replace-by-fee

I have a transaction which doesn't confirms for last 3 days and is not most likely going to confirm at all in near future due to a recent situation in mempool.

Will it be working if I'll do the following? Are there any risks to loose my bitcoins forever, or even to get banned by system for double-spend?

1. Dump that transaction with 'getrawtransaction'
2. Decrease one of it's outputs by X in my hex editor, so that X will be added up to transaction fee
3. Sign that transaction with 'signrawtransaction' and send it

Comment: Did your original transaction opt-in to RBF?

Comment: How could I know that?

Comment: Check if any of the sequence numbers on your transaction are less than 0xffffffff - 1

Comment: All are equal to 0xffffffff - 1 (0xfffffffe). This means that I don't have RBF, I guess?

Comment: Correct. So this is the answer you need: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9046/why-is-my-transaction-not-getting-confirmed-and-what-can-i-do-about-it

Comment: Thanks, I have taken a look at that article - they are saying to run bitcoin-core with special options and re-send bitcoins. But can I use sendrawtransaction exactly as described above in order to do that? I want to ensure that I will use exactly the same inputs for resending transaction, and no new inputs will be tainted during transaction re-sending.

Answer (score 1):

Could the free ViaBTC Transaction Accelerator service help you ? The service requires a minimum of fee rate of 0.0001 BTC/kB and has submission limit of 100 that is reset every full hour.
"https://pool.viabtc.com" under "Tool".

Comment: It always says "Submissions are beyond limit. Please try later."

Comment: This worked for me.  coinb.in reported a "duplicate" failure (duplication is the intent with a fee bump), and bitcoind refused the transaction because it sees the mempool transaction -- however sending transaction manually using viabtc seemed to go through.